# Cannot use Filters bsons in aggregate : Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.client.model.Filters$AndFilter

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to use the Bson provided by Filters to use them in an aggregate pipeline
I get exceptions because apparently aggregate tries to serialize the Bsons and the Filters Bsons cannot be serialized.

I get exceptions like these ones.

> Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.client.model.Filters$OperatorFilter
>
> Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.client.model.Filters$AndFilter

I cannot simply replace the `Filters.eq(key, val)` with some `new Document("$eq", new Document(key, val))` because I already have a lot of code using Filters.

My code looks like:

```
// In my real code, the Filters:OperatorFilter object comes from 
// the REST interface through several layers of code, but any Bson 
// from Filters will cause the exception 
Bson filter = Filters.eq("key", "value");

// then build the pipeline
List<Bson> operations = new ArrayList<>();

// First we reduce the scope to the visibility
// !!! This is the part of the pipeline that is problematic
if (filter != null) {
    operations.add(new Document("$match", filter)); 
}

// We group the documents by the property
Document groupFields = new Document("_id", "$" + property);
// ... don't forget to calculate the group size
groupFields.put("count", new Document("$sum", 1));
operations.add(new Document("$group", groupFields));

// We sort on the count first and then on the value
Document sort = new Document("count", -1);
sort.put("_id", 1);
operations.add(new Document("$sort", sort));
// ... and get only the biggest ones
if (limit > 0) {
     operations.add(new Document("$limit", limit));
}

// !!! the call to aggregate raises the exception
AggregateIterable<Document> groups = this.collection.aggregate(operations);
```

A very simple way to produce the exception is simply to try to serialize a `Filters:OperatorFilter` object. For example :

```
Bson bson = Filters.eq("key", "value")
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.writeValueAsString(bson)
```

I thought about using Bson:toBsonDocument but I don't now how to simply get a CodecRegistry it needs as argument.

The project is compiled with mongo-java-driver 3.4.1 but I have also tested with the latest 3.8.2 without success.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Could you add some of the code you're using to build and query the aggregate?

Answer (score 2):

When writing your aggregation pipeline use the Aggregations factory methods instead of writing them as Documents. (The same way you use Filters factory for filters)

Documentation can be found at:
http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/model/Aggregates.html

Replace these statements with:

```
new Document("$match", filter)
new Document("$group", groupFields)
new Document("$sort",  sort)
```

These:

```
Aggregates.match(filter)
Aggregates.group(groupFields)
Aggregates.sort(sort)
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day. My faith in mongo is totally restored :-)